# Unable to save and show data in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res)=> {
    var myData = new Contact(req.body);
    myData.save().then(()=>{
        res.send("Item has been saved");
    }).catch(()=>{
             res.send('Item was not saved due to some error');
    });
});
```

Later when I'm trying to put data and trying to see data from mongo shell using db.contacts.find(), the data is not there in the database. There is just an object ID and nothing else. This is what I'm seeing in the Mongo Shell--

[Picture of Mongo shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUKEB.png)

Comment: check in `req.body` that every data is getting or not.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Show me the Console.log(req.body)

Comment: console.log(req.body)  showing 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try in app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
```

and check the header of request because should have

```
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```